# Can custom model binders work in both directions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been looking into custom model binders as a way of globally intercepting and modifying specific string properties on my view model.

I can override the SetProperty and manipulate values which are being POSTed but what about the other way around?

For instance I might want to Trim() all the strings coming out of my model, is this possible with model binders or am I missing something? I have looked at overriding the GetPropertyValue but this doesn't appear to fire when the view loads.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, model binders only work in one direction.

You could create your own instance of ActionResult, for example by extending ViewResult or PartialViewResult.

Or you could implement an ActionFilterAttribute to trim the strings.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
    ...
}
```

Or you could do brute force

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string _myProp

    public string MyProp
    {
        set { _myProp = value.Trim(); }
        get { return _myProp; }
    }
}
```

...but you can't use model binders to bind model going from the controller to the view.

Comment: thanks, trying to implement the ActionFilterAttribute but how do i get access to the model from ActionExecutingContext filterContext?

Comment: See updated answer. Your model will be typed as `object`, so you would need the reflection API do trim the string properties in it.